# ASP.Net core 3.0 (3.1) set PathBase for single page application

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, single-page-application

I have the following asp.net core spa application configured (react-redux template)

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/foo"));

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

I’d like to set pathBase for application, but `app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/foo"))` just ignored. On 2.2 it perfectly worked. Automatically modified index.html and all static files were moved to relative path. But on 3.0 (3.1) static + generated files are placed on root.

[Generated files on .Net Core 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikU6N.png)

[Generated files on .Net Core 3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om3hX.png)

Does anyone have any ideas for solving it? Or may be some examples of Startup.cs with working pathBase?

Comment: Could you please share us with a demo that reproduces?

Comment: Yes, of course! [Here my project](https://github.com/anfateev/UsePathBaseProblem). I tried some methods described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). But still no solution. I can't find any code that modified index.html and any webpack configuration to determine how it generates static files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Usually, `app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/foo"));` is used because the reverse proxy cuts off some prefix and causes ASP.NET Core app doesn't realize the virtual app path is start with `/foo`. In your scenario, if you don't have a reverse proxy that rewrite the prefix to empty string, you don't need `app.UsePathBase(...)`.
2. Instead, if you your spa runs on a subpath, you could setup a middleware that branches the `/foo`.
3. Finally, you might want to add a property of `homepage` in your `package.json` so that it will generate the `<base url="/foo/"/>` when publishing. Or as an alternative, you could update the `<base url="">` in `ClientApp/public/index.html` manually.

In short, add a `"homepage": "/foo/"` in your `package.json`

```
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/foo/",
  "dependencies": {
      ...
   }
```

And setup a `/foo` branch to make SPA runs under that path:

```cs
string spaPath = "/foo";
app.Map(spaPath,appBuilder =>{
    appBuilder.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.DefaultPage = spaPath+"/index.html";
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions{
            RequestPath = spaPath,
        };
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
});
```

Don't use `app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/foo"))` unless you understand you do want to override the path base for all routes.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Webpack again generates static files in root, or if I map some path `app.Map(spaPath,appBuilder...`, can't find anything. Image here 
 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DTbQ.png. I updated my [project](https://github.com/anfateev/UsePathBaseProblem), could you view the code, please? Or give an example of application running on a subpath? Thanks a lot

Comment: Now discovered, that `index.html` automatically generated if URL ends with `/`, But still none of the methods to move `static/js` folder and `manifest.json` to relative path works. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSVGj.png

Comment: It works!!! But only with published project. If i start it via VS, it causes the errors I previously described. And one more moment: if I'd like to set relative path from some configuration, in package.json must be `"homepage": "."`

Comment: I tried a dozen of similar approaches that use MapWhen(....) but none have worked for me. I think that is because the approaches i user ignored setting .RequestPath property. Well done.