# How to setup a React app on a branch in .Net Core web app?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core

I created a .Net Core Web app with React via a predefined template on visual studio 2019. The generated app works and runs the reactjs app at the root address.

> https://localhost:44349/

Now I want to run this reactjs app on the branch address leaving me with the option of using server-side views and routes for the remaining addresses.

> https://localhost:44349/app

To achieve this, I found the following code from the following website and another question.

- https://www.strathweb.com/2017/04/running-multiple-independent-asp-net-core-pipelines-side-by-side-in-the-same-application/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225489

Following the approach suggested above, I was able to access my reactjs app via /app.

My issue is that now on running this app in development mode, it doesn't work as all the requests to /app/* returns the index page of the reactjs app, including for static resources such as js/css etc, resulting in the following errors in web console for js files

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

*Startup.cs, Configure*

```
const string spaPath = "/app";
app.Map(new PathString(spaPath), appMember =>
{
    string clientAppPath = env.IsDevelopment() ? "ClientApp" : @"ClientApp/build";

    StaticFileOptions clientAppDist = new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), clientAppPath)
            )
    };
    appMember.UseStaticFiles(clientAppDist);
    if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        appMember.UseSpaStaticFiles(clientAppDist);
    }

    appMember.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
});
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "react_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "app",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "merge": "^1.2.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "nan": "^2.14.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have already tried solutions applicable to Angular but they don't seem to work, maybe due to missing wwwroot.

Comment: I noticed you only set appMember.UseSpaStaticFiles(clientAppDist); in production and not for development, have you tried setting this for development?